# Mosquitto client can't publish message to EMQ X Broker

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, emq

I have model like this:
[image]

EMQ X Broker installed at IP 222.x.y.z.

And two Mosquitto client.

I want to publish message from Mosquitto_client_2 then receive Mosquitto_client_1.

I do like this:

Step 1: run command:

`mosquitto_sub -h 222.x.y.z -t "TEST_TEST"`

on Client_1

[image]

Step 2: EMQ X Broker auto create topic "TEST_TEST", like this
[image]

Step 3: Mosquitto client 2 publish message, run command:

`mosquitto_pub -h 222.x.y.z -t TEST_TEST -m "hello world"`

But it have problem "Error: Connection refused" like this:
[image]

I don't know the cause of the error and how to fix this error.

P/s: I also open all port for EMQ X.
[image]

Comment: Connection refused implies a firewall somewhere. Are the 2 clients on the same network 1) as each other 2) as the broker?

Comment: p.s. if this broker is publicly accessable via the internet then you really should be using authentication and probably MQTT over SSL/TLS

Comment: Thanks, I will check firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first eliminate the network problem and use telnet to determine whether the port can be accessed.

```
telnet localhost 1883

Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```